How make tabs logic
I have laravel10 prject, with vue3 and inertia
I have routers in web.php:
Route::resources([
    'roles' => RoleController::class,
    'users' => UserController::class,
]);

For example RoleController , index action:
 public function index()
    {
        return inertia('Roles/Index', [
            'roles' => Role::orderBy('id','ASC')->get()
        ]);
    }

It returns vue component
also for UserController:
 public function index()
    {
        return inertia('Users/Index', [
            'users' => User::with('roles')->get()
        ]);

    }

I also have settings page:
Route::get('settings', [SettingsController::class, 'index'])->name('settings');

Also use Vue component
class SettingsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return inertia('Settings/Index');
    }
}

I want on settings page have tabs, like this
<div class="flex flex-col border rounded-md">
        <ul class="flex overflow-x-auto px-4 py-2 rounded-t-md bg-gray-200">
            <li class="cursor-pointer relative mr-2 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 rounded-t-md"
                :class="{ 'bg-white font-bold text-gray-900': activeTab === 'roles' }"
            >
                   <Link :href="route('roles.index')">Roles</Link>

            </li>
            <li class="cursor-pointer relative mr-2 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 rounded-t-md"
                :class="{ 'bg-white font-bold text-gray-900': activeTab === 'users' }"
            >
                   <Link :href="route('users.index')">Users</Link>
            </li>
        </ul>


        <div class="px-4 py-6 border-t">
            <div class="space-y-4">
                Active tab content....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

And i want if I click on 'Roles' - will show on 'Active tab content...' content from route('roles.index') ,if click on 'Users' - show content from route('users.index')
Is it possible?
Tried to find solution like with <router-view>...
Or I need to use <slot> logic? And create like 'TabsLayout' and on pages 'Roles/Index
, 'Users/Index' use that layout
What is best solution? Thanks

Can anybody help with it?

hmm this wont work like this  remember that Laravel uses MVC architecture so basically we have controller which fetches some data and  passes that data to specific view fo display.  So possible approach would be to prepare roles and users data in your controller pass them to view which would display that data in tabs component ?

The best way to do that is with Inertia partial reload
Note: You should use the same route example /settings for example.
In your controller :
return Inertia::render('Settings', [
  'users' => Inertia::lazy(fn () => ['Jonh Doe', 'Jane Doe']), // fetch users from DB
  'roles' => Inertia::lazy(fn () => ['Admin', 'Visitor']),  // fetch roles from DB
]);

In your vuejs Settings.vue Page
<script setup>
import {router} from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import {onMounted, ref} from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
roles: {
    type: [],
    default: []
},
users: {
    type: [],
    default: []
}
});

const activeTab = ref('roles');

const navigateToTab = (tab) => {
   if (props.roles?.length === 0 && tab === 'roles') {
     router.reload({
        only: ['roles'],
        preserveScroll: true,
     });
    }else if(props.users?.length === 0 && tab === 'users'){
     router.reload({
        only: ['users'],
        preserveScroll: true,
    });
}

 activeTab.value = tab;
}

onMounted(() => navigateToTab(activeTab.value));
</script>

<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col border rounded-md">
    <ul class="flex overflow-x-auto px-4 py-2 rounded-t-md bg-gray-200">
        <li class="cursor-pointer relative mr-2 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 rounded-t-md"
            :class="{ 'bg-white font-bold text-gray-900': activeTab === 'roles' }">
            <button @click.prevent="navigateToTab('roles')">Roles</button>
        </li>
        <li class="cursor-pointer relative mr-2 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 rounded-t-md"
            :class="{ 'bg-white font-bold text-gray-900': activeTab === 'users' }">
            <button @click.prevent="navigateToTab('users')">Users</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="px-4 py-6 border-t">
        <div class="space-y-4" v-if="activeTab === 'roles'">
            {{roles}}
        </div>
        <div class="space-y-4" v-if="activeTab === 'users'">
            {{users}}
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</template>

